# Basic probabilities to have one person in different samples out of 3 groups

Tags: probability, solution-verification

The situation is the following: There are 3 groups G1 and G3 consisting of 30 and G2 of 40 people (in total 100). I'm drawing a sample of 10 using different ways.

1. Drawing three times without replacement from G1 and G3 and four times from G2.
2. Repeat the following ten times: Select the group randomly and then a person from this group (with replacement).

What is the probability to have a certain person in the sample of 10?

My solution is the following:

1. It depends of the group the person is in. Let me do it for a person of group G1. I'm drawing three people out of this group, so the chance of the certain person being there should be $$\frac{3}{30} = \frac{1}{10}.$$
2. The chance to draw the certain person (if in G1 again) is because it is with replacement:
   $$\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{30} = \frac{1}{90}.$$
   As I'm repeating this process 10 times, the chance should be multiplied by $10$ resulting in $\frac{1}{9}$. Is this correct?

What would be the case if in (2) the sample was taken without replacement (when it comes to the people in the groups)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The chance that a certain person from G1 is in the draw is the complement of the chance that s/he isn't.

$$1-\frac {29}{30}\frac{28}{29}\frac{27}{28}$$

or

$$1-\frac{{29\choose3}}{{30\choose3}}$$

2. The second one should be

$$1-\left(\frac 1 {90}\right)^{10}$$

As there is a $1/90$ chance each round of picking the person. So the chance the person is picked at least once is the above.

As for your follow-up question it would become more complicated and beyond the scope of this answer.